# Bulb Neo4j Update Error

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin, bulbs, neo4j.py

I am passing a dictionary of the form

```
{'twitterid':121212, 'followers':[121,212323,2323,1221]}
```

to the function createVertex

```
def createVertex(userDict):
    vertex = g.vertices.create(twitterid=userDict['twitterid'])
    g.vertices.update(vertex.eid, userDict)

    while not 'followers' in list(vertex.data().iterkeys()):
        print "trying " + str(vertex.twitterid)

    return vertex
```

It gets stuck in while loop. I suspect there is a "commit" issue in update or a race issue. Can someone advise how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No race condition. `vertex` doesn't contain `userDict` in the example you provided because `update()` doesn't modify it. Use `save()` instead:

```
def createVertex(userDict):
    vertex = g.vertices.create(twitterid=userDict['twitterid'])

    vertex.followers = userDict['followers']
    vertex.save()

    return vertex
```

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/element.py#L505

However, you can do all of the above in one step:

```
vertex = g.vertices.create(userDict)
```

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/element.py#L551